# How to arrange labels to make them visible when they are too close

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this plot I did using Python's `matplotlib`:

[image]

I wanted to improve it using TikZ and add some labels to it. The problem I'm having is that the labels get too close to each other and they end up being all overlapped.

[image]

Is there any way to make this plot clearer? I could take it if the blue labels were gone, but the others are quite important. I think that the plot should be rotated and the labels should be moved somehow, but unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

Edit: the position of the points can be changed (namely, `\Px`, `\Py` and `\Pz` can be modified to be whatever you want if the point is on the surface o the sphere) if that helps to make the plot clearer.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{115}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
\newcommand{\pvec}[1]{\vec{#1}\mkern2mu\vphantom{#1}}

\begin{document}
\def\Px{1/sqrt(33)}
\def\Py{4/sqrt(33)}
\def\Pz{4/sqrt(33)}
\def\Ef{1.4}
\def\Er{0.33}
\def\Qz{1.4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale = 2.5]
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);

\coordinate (P1) at ({\Px},{\Py},{\Pz});
\coordinate (dE1) at ({\Px-\Px*\Ef},{\Py-\Py*\Ef},{\Pz+(\Qz-\Pz)*\Ef});
\coordinate (P2) at ({\Py},{\Px},{\Pz});
\coordinate (dE2) at ({\Py-\Py*\Ef},{\Px-\Px*\Ef},{\Pz+(\Qz-\Pz)*\Ef});
\coordinate (P3) at ({-\Px},{-\Py},{\Pz});
\coordinate (dE3) at ({-\Px+\Px*\Ef},{-\Py+\Py*\Ef},{\Pz+(\Qz-\Pz)*\Ef});
\coordinate (P4) at ({-\Py},{-\Px},{\Pz});
\coordinate (dE4) at ({-\Py+\Py*\Ef},{-\Px+\Px*\Ef},{\Pz+(\Qz-\Pz)*\Ef});

\coordinate (Q) at (0, 0, \Qz);

\def\arrayP{(P1), (P2), (P3), (P4)}
\def\arrayE{(dE1), (dE2), (dE3), (dE4)}

% Sphere
\shade[ball color = lightgray, opacity = 0.5] (0,0,0) circle (1cm);
% Sphere's dotted lines
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};
\draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords, gray] (0,0,0) circle (1);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{90};
\draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords, gray] (1,0,0) arc (0:360:1);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{90}{90};
\draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords, gray] (1,0,0) arc (0:360:1);
\draw[dashed, gray] (O) -- (-1,0,0);
\draw[dashed, gray] (O) -- (0,-1,0);
\draw[dashed, gray] (O) -- (0,0,-1);
% Axes
\draw[-stealth] (O) -- (1.80,0,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[-stealth] (O) -- (0,1.30,0) node[below right] {$y$};
\draw[-stealth] (O) -- (0,0,2.3) node[above] {$z$};
% Charges
\foreach \p [count=\i] in \arrayP {
    \draw[thick, -stealth] (O) -- \p node[right] {$\pvec{r}'_{\i}$};
    \draw[thick, blue, -stealth] \p -- (Q) node[right] {$\vec{r}-\pvec{r}'_{\i}$};
}
% Differential fields
\foreach \p [count=\i] in \arrayE {
    \draw[thick, red, -stealth] (Q) -- \p node[left] {$d\vec{E}_{\i}$};
}
% Total field
\draw[thick, teal, -stealth] (Q) -- ($\Er*(dE1) + \Er*(dE2) + \Er*(dE3) + \Er*(dE4)$) node[right] {$\vec{E}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Two of the `P` coordinates coincide since `\Px` and `\Py` coincide up to a point. So it is not clear to me what you mean by "make clearer". These points coincide, and IMHO it doesn't make too much sense to try to discriminate them.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Oops, sorry! I forgot to fix the code before uploading it. I've edited the OP, now it's "fine". Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a perfect solution but some suggestions. You may want to

1. increase the scale by a tiny bit.;
2. draw the vectors that are inside the sphere on the background layer;
3. vary the node anchors;
4. use proper differential `d`s.

Result:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{115}

\newcommand{\pvec}[1]{\vec{#1}\mkern2mu\vphantom{#1}}

\begin{document}
\def\Px{1/sqrt(33)}
\def\Py{4/sqrt(33)}
\def\Pz{4/sqrt(33)}
\def\Ef{1.4}
\def\Er{0.33}
\def\Qz{1.4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale = pi]
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);

\coordinate (P1) at ({\Px},{\Py},{\Pz});
\coordinate (dE1) at ({\Px-\Px*\Ef},{\Py-\Py*\Ef},{\Pz+(\Qz-\Pz)*\Ef});
\coordinate (P2) at ({\Py},{\Px},{\Pz});
\coordinate (dE2) at ({\Py-\Py*\Ef},{\Px-\Px*\Ef},{\Pz+(\Qz-\Pz)*\Ef});
\coordinate (P3) at ({-\Px},{-\Py},{\Pz});
\coordinate (dE3) at ({-\Px+\Px*\Ef},{-\Py+\Py*\Ef},{\Pz+(\Qz-\Pz)*\Ef});
\coordinate (P4) at ({-\Py},{-\Px},{\Pz});
\coordinate (dE4) at ({-\Py+\Py*\Ef},{-\Px+\Px*\Ef},{\Pz+(\Qz-\Pz)*\Ef});

\coordinate (Q) at (0, 0, \Qz);

\def\arrayP{(P1), (P2), (P3), (P4)}
\def\arrayE{(dE1), (dE2), (dE3), (dE4)}

% Sphere
\shade[ball color = lightgray, opacity = 0.8] (0,0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
% Sphere's dotted lines
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};
\draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords, gray] (0,0,0) circle[radius=1];
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{90};
\draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords, gray] (1,0,0) arc (0:360:1);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{90}{90};
\draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords, gray] (1,0,0) arc (0:360:1);
\draw[dashed, gray] (O) -- (-1,0,0);
\draw[dashed, gray] (O) -- (0,-1,0);
\draw[dashed, gray] (O) -- (0,0,-1);
% Axes
\draw[-stealth] (O) -- (1.80,0,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[-stealth] (O) -- (0,1.30,0) node[below right] {$y$};
\draw[-stealth] (O) -- (0,0,2.3) node[above] {$z$};
% Charges
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\foreach \p [count=\i] in \arrayP {
    \draw[thick, -stealth] (O) -- \p;
    \ifnum\i=4
     \draw[thick, blue, -stealth] \p -- (Q) node[pos=0.8,right=1ex] {$\vec{r}-\pvec{r}'_{\i}$};
    \fi
%    
}
\end{scope}
\foreach \p [count=\i] in \arrayP {
    \path \p node[anchor=270-90*\i] {$\pvec{r}'_{\i}$};
    \ifnum\i=1
     \draw[thick, blue, -stealth] \p -- (Q) node[pos=0.6,right=1ex] {$\vec{r}-\pvec{r}'_{\i}$};
     \else
      \ifnum\i<4
       \draw[thick, blue, -stealth] \p -- (Q) node[pos=0.6,left=1ex] {$\vec{r}-\pvec{r}'_{\i}$};
      \fi
    \fi
}
% Differential fields
\foreach \p [count=\i] in \arrayE {
    \draw[thick, red, -stealth] (Q) -- \p 
    node[pos=1,anchor={-135+(\i<3 ?90*mod(\i,2):135*mod(\i+1,2))}] {$\mathrm{d}\vec{E}_{\i}$};
}
% Total field
\draw[thick, teal, -stealth] (Q) -- ($\Er*(dE1) + \Er*(dE2) + \Er*(dE3) + \Er*(dE4)$) node[right] {$\vec{E}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! It's definitely looking better. Isn't it possible to rotate the plot a little bit? For instance, the arrow for `dE_4` is too tiny because of the perspective and its label can be a bit confusing (I don't see if it corresponds to that arrow or the one next to it), and maybe changing the point of perspective can make everything clearer. Is that achievable?